# issues with stick forms in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

i'm trying to make this form sticky but it's not doing. What i'm trying to do is that from a previous form, the user enters some parameters and the HTML table is generated to this page, while another form is displayed to edit the data in the table shown above it. But the values are not displaying in the form below.

Please help me

PLEASE FORGIVE MY FORMATING I TYPED ON A MOBILE. Thanks for you patience.

```
 <?php session_start(); ?>
 <?php require 'includes/dbconnect.php' ; ?>
 <?php require 'includes/header.inc.php'; ?>

 <?php    
 $matric_no = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['matric_no']); 

 if ($_POST['matric_no'] == "")
 {
 echo"<div id=\"contentRight\">";
 echo"<idv id=\"msg\">" ;

 echo "You didn't enter a <span style=\"color:red\">Matric Number</span>";

 echo"</div>";
 echo"</div>";
 exit();
 } 

   $query = "SELECT matric_no
                     FROM students
                     WHERE matric_no = '$_POST[matric_no]'";


   $result = mysql_query($query);

   $duplicates = mysql_num_rows($result);

   if ($duplicates < 1) 
   {

   echo"<div id=\"contentRight\">";

   echo"<idv id=\"msg\">" ;

   echo "You dont have a record for <span style=\"color:red\">$matric_no</span>" ;

   echo "</div>" ;
   echo "</div>" ;
   exit();
  }


  $result = mysql_query("SELECT matric_no, first_name, last_name, other_name
  FROM students
           WHERE matric_no = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['matric_no'])."'") or die(mysql_error());


  $number_cols = mysql_num_fields($result) ;

  echo "<div id=\"contentRight\">" ;

  echo "<span class=\"header\">";

  echo "<p><b>Matric Number: ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['matric_no'])       ."</b></p>";

  echo "<table border = 1 , cellspacing = 0     , cellpadding = 2 bgcolor=lemonchiffon  >\n";

  echo "<tr align=center>\n";


  for ($i=0; $i<$number_cols; $i++)       
  {

  echo "<th>" . mysql_field_name($result, $i). "</th>\n";

  }

  echo "</tr>\n";

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
  {

    echo "<tr align=center>\n";

    for ($i=0; $i<$number_cols; $i++)
    {

        echo "<td>";

        if (!isset($row[$i])) 

        {echo "NULL";}

        else

        {echo $row[$i];}

        echo "</td>\n";

        }

        echo "</tr>\n";

        }

        echo "</table>"; 
        echo"</span>" ;

        echo"</div>"; 



       ?> 

         <br />
        <?php
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
     ?>

    <div id="contentRight"> 

      <p>

  Select the Score options you will like to update:

  <form action="student_update2.php" method="post"> 

   <ul>
      <li>Matric Number: &nbsp;<input             type="text" name="matric_no"   value="<?php echo $row['matric_no'] ; ?>">         </li><br/><br/> 
    <li>First Name: <input type="text"               name="first_name" value="<?php              echo $row['firts_name'] ; ?>"> </li><br       /><br/>
    <li>Last Name: <input type="text"               name="last_name"  value="<?php               echo $row['last_name'] ; ?>"> </li><br        /><br />
    <li>Other Names: <input type="text"          name="other_name" value="<?php          echo $row['other_name'] ; ?>"</li> <br       /><br />


   <input type="submit" name="submit"          value="Update" />
   <input type="hidden" name                          ="submitted" value="TRUE" />

<input name="Reset" type="reset"               value="Reset" />

   </ul>
     </div> 

       </div>   
  </form>  

  <?php
  }             
 require 'includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

`formmatting cleaned a little`

Comment: That must have been a pain to type on a mobile 0_0

Comment: Cant help but post the question. *passion*
(~_~)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT matric_no, first_name, last_name, other_name
                     FROM students
                     WHERE matric_no = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['matric_no'])."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Above this (approx line 99):

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
 ?>
 <div id="contentRight"> 
 <p>Select the Score options you will like to update:</p>
```

I know you have this declared once already but since you've already use `while` to cycle through the recordset already it may need to be reset.

Comment: Is that whenever i use a while statement, i must also run a query for it? I was thinking that if i ran the query and i did something like

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
AND
$row1 = mysql_affected_row($result);

after running the query, since i the SELECT statements are same.?

Comment: I forgot to say THANK YOU for the answer.. It worked like magic.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)   It wouldn't matter because you've already ran through the mysql_fetch_array once.  There's nothing left in there after going through it.  The easy fix was to just reuse the query again like I stated in my answer but a better solution would be to load the results into an array that could be iterated later with a for loop.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

    <input type="text" name="other_name      []" value = "<?php echo $row['other_            name'] ?>"

Comment: No, I mean to use the `while` loop to load everything into an array, then loop through that array instead of reloading the query each time.